# In how many ways can the sample be selected if it must have at least 2 male and 1 female mice?

Tags: combinations

A sample of 5 mice is to be chosen from 7 male and 6 female mice. In how many ways can the sample be selected if it must have at least 2 male and 1 female mice?

I tried doing 7C2 * 6C1 but it seems to be wrong as the answer is 1155 but I got 126

Comment: Hint:  just go by the number of female mice.  You need at least $1$ and at most $5$.

Comment: @lulu You mean at most three female mice? (A little slip there I suppose.)

Comment: @ParclyTaxel  Exactly, thanks for the correction.

Comment: @lulu ah thank you two! I understand now

Comment: Just accept my answer now, will you? (Click the green tick beside my answer.)

Comment: @ParclyTaxel so sorry! stackexchange wouldn't let me accept just now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a selection to meet the conditions, it must be exactly one of the following types (as may be seen by considering what genders the "optional" mice may have):

- 4 male 1 female: $\binom74\binom61=210$ ways
- 3 male 2 female: $\binom73\binom62=525$ ways
- 2 male 3 female: $\binom72\binom63=420$ ways

The number of possible selections is $210+525+420=1155$.